# How to add widget to a **specific** window in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I'm trying to make a multi-window application using Tkinter in Python, but there are some problems with adding widgets to Windows: all of them are just placed inside the first one.

The question is *how can I specify a window to add widgets in and is it even possible?*

Here is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from threading import Thread
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import time
import pyautogui

screenW,screenH=pyautogui.size().width,pyautogui.size().height
mainPath=input()

class Window(Thread):
    windows=[]
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon=True
    def run(self):
        self.w=Tk()
        '''
        self.w.geometry("1400x1000")
        self.w.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",lambda:self.close())
        self.w.attributes("-fullscreen",True)
        self.w.configure(bg="black")
        '''
        c=Canvas(width=screenW-20,height=screenH,bg="#4d411f",highlightbackground="#454a23")
        c.place(x=10,y=0)
        c.create_rectangle(0,10,screenW,screenH-20,outline="#362014",dash=5)
        '''
        print("window shown\n")
        Window.windows.append(self)
        '''
        self.w.mainloop()
    '''
    def close(self):
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit","Really want to quit app?"):
            self.w.destroy()
            Window.windows.remove(self)
    '''
    @staticmethod
    def openGraphsWindow():
        graphsWindow=Window()
        graphsWindow.start()
root=Window()
root.start()
while(root==None):pass
graphsButton=Button(bg="black",text="graphs",fg="white",command=Window.openGraphsWindow)
graphsButton.place(x=screenW/2-screenW//6,y=screenH/2-screenH//6,width=screenW//6,height=screenH//6)
while(root!=None):time.sleep(1)
```

Note, that when `graphsButton` is pressed, canvas are added twice to the `root` window, and that's the problem! I need to put it into `graphsWindow` instead.

Comment: Just specify the window as the first argument when creating those widgets.

Comment: @acw1668,
1) Thanks a lot
2) How is it called? (If I want to type `arg=value`, what there should be instead of "arg")

Comment: Like `c = Canvas(self.w, ...)` or `c = Canvas(master=self.w, ...)`.  Note that it is better to run tkinter stuff in the main thread.

Comment: Only one window events can be handled in one thread, so I have to use many of them.